# How to add a checkbox to the nopcomerce form

Tags: c#, asp.net, nopcommerce

I am doing a project in nopcomerce. I need a check box in product registration page. I done the following steps

Aded following code in

> [ProjectRoot]\Libraries\Nop.Core\Domain\Catalog\Product.cs

```
public bool IsSeatPlane { get; set; }
```

> [Project Root]\Libraries\Nop.Data\Mapping\Catalog\CategoryMap.cs

```
this.Property(m => m.IsSeatPlane).IsOptional();
```

> [ProjectRoot]\Presentation\Nop.Web\Administration\Models\Catalog\ProductModel.cs

```
[NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.Catalog.Products.Fields.IsSeatPlane")]
    public bool IsSeatPlane { get; set; }
```

> [Project
>   Root]\Presentation\Nop.Web\Administration\Validators\Catalog\ProductValidator.cs

```
RuleFor(m => m.IsSeatPlane);
```

> [Project Root]\Presentation\Nop.Web\Administration\Views\Category\
>   _CreateOrUpdate.cshtml

```
   <div class="form-group @(Model.ProductEditorSettingsModel.AllowCustomerReviews ? null : "advanced-setting")">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.IsSeatPlane)
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        @Html.NopEditorFor(model => model.AllowCustomerReviews)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsSeatPlane)
                    </div>
                </div>
```

> [Project
>   Root]\Presentation\Nop.Web\Administration\Controllers\ProductController.cs

In the function `PrepareProductModel`

```
model.IsSeatPlane = product.IsSeatPlane;
```

And added a field in database,but not able to display check box on the view.

Comment: Which version of nopCommerce are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to add one column in a Product table or Category table?

Please check this image. you updated `_CreateOrUpdate.cshtml` for Category folder. And your property `IsSeatPlane { get; set; }` is in Product.cs

[image]

You have to change in Product folder and `_CreateOrUpdate.cshtml` for product.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote mapping code in the **CategoryMap**. But I think it was typo mistake, as if **IsSeatPlane** is not in the **Category** class, you didn't find it there. 
So I assume you did it in the **ProductMap**. However mapping is not required for the Boolean fields. So you can remove this safely.

Entries in the **ProductValidator** is useless. You didn't mention any validation rule.

You put **IsSeatPlane** in the **ProductModel**. So I assume again there is a typo mistake. View location was

> [Project Root]\Presentation\Nop.Web\Administration\Views\Product\ _CreateOrUpdate.cshtml

instead of

> [Project Root]\Presentation\Nop.Web\Administration\Views\Category\ _CreateOrUpdate.cshtml

Now in the cshtml file, there are 2 mistakes:

[image]

First take a close look at the line marked by 1

```
 <div class="form-group @(Model.ProductEditorSettingsModel.AllowCustomerReviews ? null : "advanced-setting")">
```

Here you copied the div section from **AllowCustomerReviews** section. nopCommerce 3.8 introduces basic and advanced fields in the several admin areas. And a **settings** in the product page to indicate which fields you are interested in while inserting a product.

[image]

So if you put **advanced-setting** class in the div, it will only appear when you switch from **Basic** to **Advanced**.

If you want to always show the field, simply use **form-group** class only.

Mark 2 is pretty straight forward. it would be `model.IsSeatPlane`

So, final div block:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.IsSeatPlane)
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    @Html.NopEditorFor(model => model.IsSeatPlane)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsSeatPlane)
                </div>
            </div>
```

That's all.